# Comparing two columns in excel, inserting blank rows moving associated data

Tags: excel

I have a large set of data in excel that needs to be matched by column. Specifically, the data currently looks like:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
1          1         aaaa
2          3         bbbb
3          4         cccc
4
```

Ideally, I want the data to look like:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
1         1        aaaa
2
3         3        bbbb
4         4        cccc
```

I've looked at different ways of comparing Column 1 and Column 2 (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500352/how-to-align-matching-values-in-two-columns-in-excel-and-bring-along-associated)), but haven't found a good way to a) insert the blank space where column 1 and 2 don't match and b) also attach the data in column 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want / can use directly Excel:

[image]

In the cells of Col "D" put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2;$B$2:$B$8;);"")
```

In the cells of Col "E" put this formula:

```
=IF(D2<>"";INDEX($B$2:$C$8;D2;1);"")
```

In the cells of Col "F" put this formula:

```
=IF(D2<>"";INDEX($B$2:$C$8;D2;2);"")
```

Copy and paste for all the cells.
The good think it's that it's autoupdated... Or when finish copy and paste with value.

Comment: This worked perfectly - exactly what I needed - thank you very much! (though I had to swap the semi colon's for commas in the formulas for my Excel 2007 worksheet)

Comment: for excel beginners like me...  IFERROR is just a way of supressing #N/A where no value is found.   =IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$8,0),"") -ie. search for the value in A2 in the list B2 to B8, 0 is an exact match.  Column E  Formula for column E  =IF(D2<>"",INDEX($B$2:$C$8,D2,1),"")   This translates to give me the nth item in the list in column B (skip blank entries).  D2,1  search for D2 in column 1 i.e column B.  Column F  -- same except search in second column to return text column aaaa etc