# How to align rows of data on Excel (with 7 columns)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have it so matching words in each column line up with each other on the same rows. This forum began to explain how to do it: [How to align duplicates on the same rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836396/how-to-align-duplicates-on-the-same-rows-in-excel) it began to work with brettdj's comment in VBA, but I'm not sure how to make it work for my data. I have seven columns of data, and each have a different number of rows. The longest one is 2087 rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Please keep in mind that we cannot see your computer screen. Add some redacted sample data together with expected results to your question. Some show of your own attempt at arriving at a resolution would be great.

Comment: Did you look at the link I put in the question? If you click on it, it shows an example just like what I'm looking for, except mine is seven columns and not two.