# Row data for specific column headers based on row ID

Tags: vba, excel, function, lookup

I have a worksheet with a few hundred rows of employee data.  At its most basic level it lists **`EmployeeID`**'s, **`Name`** and lists the ***skills*** that they have.

What I have done is on *another* worksheet (in my *`Employee Lookup`* workbook) I have used a combination of the index and match functions to look up an `EmployeeID` that I enter and return the skill level from the employee skills data sheet.

What I want to do is try to simplify how the data is obtained (I have limited vba knowledge but some excel formula knowledge, hence nesting index match). The *`Employee Skills`* sheet has `Column A` with `EmployeeID`s and `Row A` with *skill names* (and prior headers).

I can set up the `Index`/`Match` for each row but then I need the *column numbers* for each skill and look up that `EmployeeID` and return the skills (even if they are *blank*).

I wouldn't really bother with trying to figure out how to begin to code this but I would think there would be an easier way to do this than making an `Index`/`Match` formula for each referenced skill (with there being anywhere from **~15-50 skills per department** when I assist with 4 departments).

The `Index`/`Match` functions would take a lot of time and already has for one group. I don't think what I am wanting can be done in Excel but unfortunately that is the data resource I am left with.

### **Example of spreadsheet layout:**

[image: Example of spreadsheet layout]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm having bit of trouble following your explanation.   The top of that image is what you have, and the bottom is what you want?

Comment: ...if so, you shouldn't need need VBA.  I believe *one* formula will do the trick; the key is to using the "correct mix" of dynamic & absolute references.  In fact, if I understand what you're trying to do, VBA would overcomplicate.

Comment: @ashleedawg what you are stating is correct, The top is the data sheet and the bottom is my lookup sheet (in another workbook). 

I would want the skills of Bob (listed top to bottom, as on the look up sheet) if I enter his employee ID in the lookup cell.

Comment: I have the index and nested match functions with appropriate references but maybe I am doing the dynamic and absolute bit wrong as I have to edit the references manually myself :( quite tedious honestly.

Comment: ...so for example, you would enter an employee number in `B9`, and you would want `B12 to B15` to auto-populate?  Or would the list of skills `A12 to A15` also need to change depending on the employee?

Comment: ...so for example, you would enter an employee number in `B9`, and you would want `B12 to B15` to auto-populate?  Or would the list of skills `A12 to A15` also need to change depending on the employee??  Also, with correctly written formulas (or VBA), you should only ever have to type something once. :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg the skills for the department are all the same so they could remain listed in the column even if that employee doesn't have the skill.

Comment: I'll put together an example in a couple mins...

Comment: @ashleedawg I had the formulas once and the references got deleted and the columns for the skills were referenced and I had to look up each individual lot so it was tedious and I wanted to see how to simplify it. That's what led me here :)

Comment: *individual skill

Comment: VBA definitely has many powerful applications (and you *should* learn it!) but in this case would be more tedious, especially if you're new to VBA.  Gimme a couple mins...

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot, I figured the absolute references would be the way to go but I was unsure how that would affect the columns (but I guess it doesn't) because it's just referencing the cells in the header row.

Comment: np, gets easier with practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer:

<sup>(A detailed & color-coded screenshot breaking down the formula is further down, or full-screen `.PNG` **[here](https://image.ibb.co/dyxxtm/SO_screenshot_2_D_Index_Match.png)**.)</sup>

**Here's a solution using sample data similar to yours:**

[image: screenshot example #1]

The "short version" of the formula in `D16` is:

```
=INDEX($C$4:$I$8,MATCH($D$11,$A$4:$A$8,0),MATCH(C16,$C$3:$I$3,0))
```

The *actual* formula I used looks scarier but it's just the above formula twice (copy/pasted) along with an `IF` so that it will bring over a blank cell if the "source cell" is blank (like Jane's Partying score)...

```
=IF(INDEX($C$4:$I$8,MATCH($D$11,$A$4:$A$8,0),MATCH(C16,$C$3:$I$3,0))=0,"",INDEX($C$4:$I$8,MATCH($D$11,$A$4:$A$8,0),MATCH(C16,$C$3:$I$3,0)))
```

Once that formula is in `D16`, I just "filled down" (or copy/paste) to the other skills.

- Note that ***all*** cell references in the above formula are "**Absolute**" *except* for `C16`.

We want ***all*** cell ranges to stay the same even if we copy/paste (or fill) the cell to another cell... *except* for C16: that's what our lookups are *based on* so that once *does* need to change when we copy the cell elsewhere.

---

## *"Two-dimensional Index/Match" Example:*

[image: screenshot example #2]

> ### Download `.xslx` sample file:
>
> To get a better idea of how it works, you can **download** the Excel file from my screenshot **[here](https://storage.jumpshare.com/download/FKdEI1MHFFMcOmklF1ZICsHOZNjatt-lUCuq2WvF1gve3hucf5aC-Ez7HS_xUOtUFsh649UsyeAU1tdvgLCAqg)** to experiment, modify, and adapt as desired.
>
> <sup>It's a direct-download link to a **Macro-free `.XSLX`**, hosted by [Jumpshare](http://%60.xslx%60/), which allows you to view [online](http://jmp.sh/DCOoJSR) but it doesn't like complex formulae, and the columnar formatting is messed up on some browsers (however you can also download from the online viewer with the <kbd>DOWNLOAD</kbd> button at the ↗**top-right**↗ of the viewer.</sup>

---

### *`INDEX` & `MATCH` Function Documentation & More Examples:*

- Microsoft (Office.com): **[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) and [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) functions *(with videos)***
- Microsoft: [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9?ocmsassetID=HP010342940&CorrelationId=1e9c570a-c73d-4a3f-8ca6-ca0fd66df56a)
- ExcelJet: [Two-way lookup with INDEX and MATCH](https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match)
- MSDN: [Performing Two-Dimensional Lookups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750573.aspx)
- mbaExcel: [Tutorial: How to Decide Which Excel Lookup Formula to Use](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/tutorial-how-to-decide-which-excel-lookup-formula-to-use/)
- Stack Overflow: [Index/Match with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836474/8112776)
- ExcelTip: [How To Use Index/Match for 2 Criteria with VBA](http://www.exceltip.com/tips/how-to-use-index-match-for-2-criterias-using-vba.html)

---

## A Crash-Course on Absolute vs. Relative Cell References

**Cell Reference** — A cell reference refers to a cell or a range of cells on a worksheet and can be used in a formula so that Microsoft Office Excel can find the values or data that you want that formula to calculate.  <sub>([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa))</sub>

> ***By default***, a cell reference is **relative**. For example, when you refer to cell `A2` from cell `C2`, **you are actually referring to a cell that is two columns to the left** (`C` minus `A`), and in the same row (`2`). A formula that contains a relative cell reference changes as you copy it from one cell to another.
>
> As an example, if you copy the formula `=A2+B2` from cell `C2` to `D2`, the formula in `D2` adjusts to the right by one column and becomes `=B2+C2`. If you want to maintain the original cell reference in this example when you copy it, you make the cell reference **absolute** by preceding the columns (`A` and `B`) and row (2) with a dollar sign (`$`). Then, when you copy the formula `=$A$2+$B$2` from `C2` to `D2`, the formula stays exactly the same.
>
> In less frequent cases, you may want to make a cell reference "**mixed**" by preceding either the column or the row value with a dollar sign to "lock" either the column or the row (for example, `$A2` or `B$3)`.

[image: Chart: Compare 4 types of cell references]<sub>([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9))</sub>

---

>

> **"Regional Afterthought"**:
>
> While answering a question about *[Excel's regional differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48375926/8112776)*, I wondered if `$` is the *international* symbol for Absolute References, or whether the symbol varied "across the pond"[.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/across_the_pond)
>
> > ("Will Brexit change *"U.K. Absolutes"* from `=€A€1` to `=£A£1`?!")
>
> A quick search revealed that the `$` is indeed the "worldwide" symbol used for Excel Absolutes — however some users (having never typed a `$` before) had trouble locating it.  Here's a link describing [How to type the `$` Dollar Sign on Non-American Keyboards](https://matadornetwork.com/abroad/the-ultimate-guide-to-computer-keyboards-around-the-world/)...

---

Good luck with your project! Let me know if you have any questions...

Comment: @ashleedawg I think part of this is with index match I've only used index to reference one column, where you have $C$4:$I$4 I only had $C:$C (I believe, the remaining formula are on my work computer). So I'll have to dissect that more tomorrow so I know why that array is a better option.

Comment: @jnjustice — Download the `.XLSX` example (direct link **[here](https://storage.jumpshare.com/download/FKdEI1MHFFMcOmklF1ZICsHOZNjatt-lUCuq2WvF1gve3hucf5aC-Ez7HS_xUOtUFsh649UsyeAU1tdvgLCAqg)**) and play with the formulas, and they should make more sense.  (You were halfway there on your own!) ...Take note of which sections of each `Index`/`Match` formula are *relative* and which are ***$absolute$***  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ashleedawg so I updated the excel sheet with the formula and I get an **#N/A** error.

The formula as the data is updated is:

`=IF(INDEX($S$2:$BH$1000,MATCH($A$7,$A$2:$A$1000,0),MATCH(A16,$S$1:$BH$1,0))=0,"",INDEX($S$2:$BH$1000,MATCH($A$7,$A$2:$A$1000,0),MATCH(A16,$S$1:$BH$1,0)))`

I have updated your numbers from the formula:

`Before:

$C$4:$I$8 
$D$11 
$A$4:$A$8 
C16 
$C$3:$I$3 

After:
$S$2:$BH$1000 
$A$7
$A$2:$A$1000
A16
$S$1:$BH$1`

Comment: When troubleshooting a formula, break it down into smaller formulas to see what result you get from each part. Your formula is `=MATCH($A$7,$A$2:$A$1000,0)` (looking in `A2:A1000` to find an exact match for the value in `A7`) **and** `=MATCH(A16,$S$1:$BH$1,0)` (looking in `S1:BH1` to find an exact maych for the value in `A16`.)  Is that what you intended?  What do you get when you enter one of those two formulas into a cell by itself?  (**Notice** that I left off the `IF` formula for now, for troubleshooting.)

Comment: ...and then if you still can't find the mistake, tell me what value is in cells 'A7` and `A16`, and which "position" in each range you find those values.

Comment: @jnjustice — Did you get it figured out?

Comment: I did not see your reply until today and I will check again at work tomorrow when have access to the data. @ashleedawg

Comment: @ashleedawg there was no error with the formula, I had the wrong reference conlumn for the employee ID to look up. The formula itself will say me a lot of time because I was not looking things up based on the skill name in the look up sheet but now if I update those it will save a lot of time (where as before if the columns changed I would have to adjust manually)