# Microsoft Excel - How to calculate sum of a column based of two different columns as conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I SUM a set of value from a columns, with 2 different columns as a condition for the calculation?

```
Month          Code           Value    
  4             A              50 
  4             A              20    
  4             B              20    
  5             A              30    
  5             B              20    
  5             B              30
```

The desired outcome should be a SUM of `Value` column that has the same `Month` and `Code` altogether:

```
 Month          Code         SumValue
   4             A              70
   4             B              20
   5             A              30
   5             B              50
```

I tried using IF, but IF could only take 1 parameter as the condition, is there any built in function of Ms Excel that could help with this?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: what you're looking for is `SUMIFS`.  See my answer & screenshot below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIFS` is a function for summing cells where multiple other ranges match certain crtieria.

In the case of your example:

[image: example SUMIFS]

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,4,B2:B7,"A")
```

...sums values in `C2:C7` where `A2:A7 = 4` and `B2:B7 = "A"`.

### More Information:

- Office.com : [Sum values based on multiple conditions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e?ocmsassetID=HA102809345&CorrelationId=f1a39d1a-abff-4608-8129-32d6438588de)
- ExcelTrick : [Excel SUMIF and SUMIFS – Explained](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-sumif-and-sumifs/)

Comment: This answer won't copy properly if OP attempts to copy it to address the precise question because the references are not absolute and columns A and B are not even referenced.

Comment: @JohnJoseph -- I don't see that as a requirement in the OP's question.  If the OP also needs a lesson on absolute/relative references then I'd be happy to add or point in the right direction.  ...but thank you for expanding on your original answer fragment.

Comment: @ashleedawg yes, it was not a requirement that i ask for a copy and paste ready solution, the problem was a toned-down version of the actual data after all (151584 row, 275 column) can't copy them all here.

Even though not 100% accurate. You helped gave me insights tho, thanks!

In the case, it should work with:
`=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,4,$B$2:$B$7,"A")`

Since the column ranges `A, B and C` won't be changing along with the parameters `4 and A`

Please update your answer and that should be perfect :)

Comment: You've got it :-)  I will also add a note on 2-dimensional relative/absolute references. I actually had an explanation typed out recently... (*now where did I put it..*)

Comment: @ErickVanhite -- in the meantime, you my find [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48534323/8112776) also to be useful

Answer (score 1):

SUMIFS ... note the S.  Couldn't be easier. :-)
[image]

Comment: It wasn't me (since i am not 125 rep yet), but you could actually provide some clearer solution instead of looking down on the problem. So the downvote was justified