# Using VLOOKUP with two different Excel Files (workbooks)

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am having trouble using VLOOKUP within two different excel files (Not two sheets).

- One File contain the terminal Log with dates, Product name and Output (Calculated).
- The other file contain total analyzed about the same product name and all.

I want to include those output (Calculated) from 1st workbook to 2nd workbook.
Note that they contain same product name under title "商品名".

What I have tried:

```
 VLOOKUP([1stfile!productname,1stfile!$productname$1:ProductnameEndcolumn,5,0)
```

All i get is same number "616" in the whole column.

**Actual Code**:
    =VLOOKUP(Trn.txt!$I$1,Trn.txt!$I$1:$M$7216,5,0)

Here Trn.txt is firstfile

```
I1 is the column where it contains product name
m7216 is End point of product name column
5 is the Output(Calculated)column which I want
0 False = Exact Match
```

I only get the product value of 1st product which is 616. And when I Ctrl+click drag to bottom, every cell has same value 616.

Answer (score 0):

I have a terrible memory, so I often forget how to reference different cells/worksheets/files.

So, I just *let Excel figure it out for me...*

[image: screenshot]

Ah yes, I remember now.  The correct syntax is:

```
=[WorkbookName]SheetName!CellReference
```

for example:

```
='C:\myPath\[myWorkbook.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

I trust you'll be able to adapt that to your `VLOOKUP` without issue.

---

Something else that may be of benefit to you is the *"Crash Course"* on **Relative vs Absolute cell references** at the bottom of [my answer **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533663/row-data-for-specific-column-headers-based-on-row-id/48534323#48534323).

Answer (score 0):

When you're having trouble remembering the correct syntax in formulas, particularly references like this, it can be useful to use the *Fx* button just to the left of the formula bar after you've typed "=VLOOKUP(".

It opens up the function's arguments and allows you to click into what you need to reference, instead of typing it in (and remembering how to do it).